# Confusing .align address arrangement

Tags: assembly, dump, memory-alignment

I was looking at the address assignments.

```
00010004 <arr>: 10004: 10080402 .word 0x10080402 10008: 20 .byte 0x20 
00010009 <eoa>: 10009: 00 .byte 0x00 ... 
0001000c <start>: ...
```

Assembly part of the code:

```
.section .text.ResetISR
.align
.global ResetISR
.type ResetISR, %function

ResetISR:
   b start

arr:
  .byte 2, 4, 8, 16, 32

eoa:
  .align

start: ...
```

---

Why does the address of *eoa* start at `00010009`. It should be starting at `0001000d`, right?
Why does *start* address the memory from `0001000c` and not from `0001000d`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the *eoa* label will the padding by the `.align` directive **start**.
This means that the *eoa* label itself simply follows the 5 bytes array that ended at 00010009h.

The padding then inserts 3 null bytes, putting the *start* label 3 bytes further at 0001000Ch.

---

> It should be starting from "0001000d" right?

I think you believe the `.align` directive inserts a fixed amount of bytes in the code (00010005h + 8 = 0001000Dh).
What it does however is inserting *a calculated number of padding bytes* to have the **following code** at an aligned address.